# React native, recreate ios and android folders

Tags: android, ios, expo, react-native

Couple of days ago I upgraded react-native project and also changed a lot of settings in my android and ios folders. After that it stopped to work properly and I deleted it. Now, I want to regenerate ios & android folder and make it work with my existing code. The question is: how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Expo? or straight up react native?

Comment: @Shai, I've used expo, but then I ejected project

Comment: So when you do "expo eject" again it doesnt re created the ios and android folders?

Comment: @Shai, holly..., thanks, I didn't know that "expo eject" can be used more than once

Comment: As much as you want, just notice if you do changes on the android or ios folder and do eject again it can delete it because it will go back to what was originally extract from teh react native code :) will post it as an answer then for future people that get stuck in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,
If you are using Expo as your development tool for react native, you can always reset the android and ios folders by running:

```
expo eject
```

from the command line when ever you need, just notice it will override changes made directly on these folders, so eject cerfully.